Confusion regarding the field due to a dielectric
I have a doubt regarding the total field due to a system having dielectric. If I have a linear dielectric, so I will have
D = εE .
Also if the dielectric is homogeneous, I can have
∇• D = ρ(f) and ∇× D = ∇× (εΕ) = ε(∇× Ε ) = 0
(except at the boundary where ε is not constant with position) , where ρ(f) represents the volumetric free charge density. So, since I know the curl and divergence of D, I can find it explicitly as
D = 1/4π ∫ρ(f)r/r³ dτ ,
which is same as
D = ε0E(f) ,
where E(f) is the field due to free charges in the system . So from the above two equations for D, it can be deducted that
E = E(f)/ε',
where ε'= ε/ε0.
The constraints for this type of system seems to be very less , being only linearity and homogeneity of the dielectric. So this relation seems to solve wide range of problems, one simple looking is as follows: I placed a spherical linear homogeneous dielectric (ε') in an uniform electric field E0. I want to know the total field in the space due to the system after the polarisation of dielectric . Since linearity and homogeneity is confirmed both inside and outside the sphere. I may be able to conclude that
E(inside) = E0/ε'
and
E(outside) = E0.
But it turns out that the field outside is not even uniform and also the field inside is constant but some other i.e.
E(inside) = 3/(ε'+2) E0
So what is wrong in my reasoning?
I have studied this topic from "Introduction to Electrodynamics" by David J. Griffiths.

I am confused by your notation. If the dielectric is uniform, why write it as a function of $\bf r$, $\epsilon({\bf r})$? Also the phrase "non-bound" charge is non-standard (iirc--it has been a few decades), but we usually talk about "free charge", and then any induced charges from $\nabla\cdot\vec P$ are absorbed into $\vec D$. So is the question about a uniform spherical dielectric placed in a constant external electric field, $\vec E = E \hat z$?

@JEB  Sorry for the confusing notations , I have edited those notations and phrases. Yes I am pointing out the same example as you are mentioning

As Griffiths explains, the electric displacement $\mathbf{D}$ cannot in general be calculated from Coulomb's law, i.e.
$$\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{r}) \neq \frac{1}{4\pi} \int \rho_f (\mathbf{r}')\frac{(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|^3} \mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{r}'.$$
There are special cases for which such a formula works, such as $\varepsilon$ being constant for all space, making $\nabla\times\mathbf{D}=\mathbf{0}$ everywhere. However, as your example shows, having $\nabla\times\mathbf{D}=\mathbf{0}$ for just one point or region is not a sufficient condition. Therefore, your first few lines of reasoning are false.
When a homogeneous linear dielectric sphere is placed in a uniform external electric field $\mathbf{E}_0$, it acquires a net polarization due to separation of charge. This net polarization itself gives rise to an electric field, which then changes the polarization, and so on until the final result is reached. Therefore, the electric field outside the sphere is not $\mathbf{E}_0$. Both $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{E}$ are unknowns which is why another method is usually used (in this case, solving Laplace's equation in spherical coordinates). However, it is possible to obtain the answer by following the iterative description above; Prob. 4.23 does exactly that.

Shouldn't D(outside) be equal to ε0E0 because vaccum is homogeneous and linear and similarly D(inside)=ε0Ε0? Could you please explain this point?

@AnujGour No, and that is exactly what I said in my answer. The polarized sphere produces a field as well, so the electric field with the sphere present is not $\mathbf{E}_0$, and therefore $\mathbf{D} \neq \varepsilon_0\mathbf{E}_0$. (For clarity, $\mathbf{E}_0$ is the external applied field, i.e. the field with nothing present.)

But the charges on the sphere produced from polarisation would be bound charges, so why is it affecting the value of D?

@AnujGour Who said that bound charge does not affect $\mathbf{D}$? Clearly $\mathbf{E}$ is still the sum of the fields produced by all charges, free and bound, and $\mathbf{D}=\varepsilon\mathbf{E}$, so $\mathbf{D}$ too depends on the total charge, free and bound. I suggest reading section 4.3.2 again.

@AnujGour It is true that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{D}$ is independent of the bound charge, but that does not mean that $\mathbf{D}$ is independent of the bound charge.

Alright , so I thought that if we know curl and divergence of a field at a particular point, then we can find the field at the same point. But this is of course not true because we need ρ(r') not ρ(r) to find the field , so we need to know how ρ is changing in space and similarly we need to know how curl is changing in space. Working at a particular region won't help as you said .Thank you for giving this your time.

One last thing I want to clarify, it is that why then we do use D=ε0E0 in the system of parallel plate capacitors with a dielectric between them.

@AnujGour What is $E_0$ in that case? Note that the permittivity is not $\varepsilon_0$ in the dielectric.

E0 is the field without the dielectric (Example 4.6).

@AnujGour It depends on whether the potential difference or the charge is held constant. The former corresponds to a capacitor connected to a emf source: the electric field remains unchanged as $V/d$. The latter corresponds to a capacitor that is given some charge and then isolated: the electric field changes.
